# Build.VERSION.SDK_INT has illegal value

Tags: android

My application supports android version 2.3.3 (SDK 10) and above. I have a simple code:

```
private void setBackgroundToView(View view, Drawable drawable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        view.setBackground(drawable);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

I found that on GT-I9100G with android 4.0.3 which would have sdk version 15 follow log:

```
I/dalvikvm(13683): Could not find method android.view.View.setBackground, referenced from method %some_package%.setBackgroundToView
```

It means that `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` has value more than 15.

1. How can I prevent illegal calling of unsupported method in this case?
2. Have every devices and os versions with firmwares same sdk_int for same SDK versions?
3. Can I use Build.VERSION.RELEASE to additional check number of version?

Comment: You could check for the presence of the `setBackground` method using [reflection](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the log is tagged `I` for information, not `E` for error.

The class loader loads the code and while verifying the bytecode, it finds a call to a missing method and logs it. The code itself is not executed, you would get `NoSuchMethodError` if it was.

Your `SDK_INT` value works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `setBackgroundDrawable` always?

Also, you should debug the `SDK-INT` version of that device, instead of only assuming it is 15 or so.

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, i would just use setBackgroundDrawable as you dont have any advantages of setBackground, anyways.

If you still want to use it. Recheck the SDK version of your device. I dont know any device where Build.VERSION.SDK_INT isnt set properly. You could also do a try/catch and fall back to setBackgroundDrawable if setBackground raises an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16){
        rl.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(image));
    } else {
        rl.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(image));
    }
```

Ok, you can always use `setBackgroundDrawable` as mentioned above, but if you don't, code above works perfectly.